# Jquery mobile when used in the website it effects the older design and classes

Tags: html, jquery-ui, css, jquery-mobile

I have a general question . That is I have been working on a mobile website for already existing website .

I was doing the css myself for the pages. But now I want to include the Jquery mobile Ui for some of the elements like forms,input button sliders etc.

My question is when I load the mobile Ui into my website it effects other design too like all the buttons got changed even though they have there separate classes . Also the loader is just taking too much time to shift from one page to other it shows a circle always revolving and does nothing .

I am new to this kindly instruct me how to use mobile Jquery for my already designed pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Custom CSS and you don't want JQM to apply its CSS Styles to you Elements Use the Following

**data-role="none"**

**data-enhance="false"**

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.2/docs/forms/forms-all-native.html

The documentation says "To activate this functionality, $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled must be set to true."

add this Before the JQM js file in the HEAD

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled=true;
});
```